# Polymer iron-ajax events "on-response" and "on-error" not working on Mozilla FF

Tags: firefox, dom, polymer, iron-ajax

Dears,
I'm using "iron-ajax"s events to show a success/failure message. For this i'm using respectively "on-response" and "on-error". It is working fine in "Chrome" but it's not triggered in "Mozilla Firefox". Here is a simple example :

```
<iron-ajax contentType="{{contentType}}" method="{{method}}" on-response="msgSavedResponse" on-error="msgSavedError" id="ajax" url="{{url}}" headers="{{headers}}" handle-as="json"
           last-response="{{lastResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Then below in Polymer, I have the following methods :

```
  msgSavedResponse: function(){
      this.$.successToast.text=this.localize('msg.success');
      this.$.successToast.show();
      this.$.messageDialog.close();  
  },
  msgSavedError: function(){
      this.$.errorToast.text=this.localize('msg.fail');
      this.$.errorToast.show();
      this.$.messageDialog.close();  
  },
```

Comment: Does the ajax call never happen, or it just never hits those response functions?

Comment: The call is correctly done and I receive a HTTP 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `event` argument to your handler. For me the events normally worked in FX - does your console show any errors?

You can also set `bubbles` property to true and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it didn't help. There are no error message in the console

Comment: My apologizes. The bubbles=true made the difference ! 
I didn't notice it because Firefox kept the old .html in cache.
Thanks a lot !